# Network connection problems on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server?

Tags: 10.04, networking

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on a Dell PowerEdge T410 and using a wired network connection. Whenever system becomes idle, it looses network connection.

I needed to either logout or restart the machine in order to make network connections work. However, I have another Dell server running 10.04 LTS and it is working fine.

```
$ lspci 
... ...
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
... ...

$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-user 2.6.32-34-server #77-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 20:54:38 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 $ tail -300 /var/log/kern.log | grep "Nov  4"
Nov  4 12:36:34 ubuntu-user kernel: [161497.534069] npviewer.bin[17951]: segfault at eeb740a4 ip 00000000f5d74c83 sp 00000000ff8d4ed0 error 4 in libflashplayer.so[f58f7000+fc7000]

$ tail -10 /var/log/pm-powersave.log
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/powersave-policy-hda-powerdown false:success.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false:**sched policy powersave OFF
success.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm true:success.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron true:stop: Unknown instance: 
success.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/powersave-policy-dirty-writeback true:success.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/powersave-policy-hda-powerdown true:success.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave true:**sched policy powersave ON
success.
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: I would check /var/log/kern.log for more information. Seems odd for an interface to drop off the face of the earth without a message in kern.log

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion. Please see the updated question. There is only one error message (for today). Do you think that is the reason? Please let me know.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: You know what, I have exactly the same issue on two different AMD machines.  It would periodically loose networking and then come alive again after maybe a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that "system becomes idle" means "screensaver activated" or "lid closed", and suggest that the Power Manager is your culprit. Look at `/var/log/pm-*.log` 
and `man pm-powersave`

Comment: If I deactivate the screensave (i.e. blank screensaver), can I overcome the problem.

Comment: That was a step I took, too. But then I learned about Power Manager, and now I've told Power Manager NOT to mess with my network. That's the knowledge that I hope I've encapsulated in my answer above.

Comment: I have update my question with pm-powersave.log details. Please let me know if there something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell, from the log fragment you posted. DO NOT post your whole log. Run this command: `grep -i -n -B2 fail /var/log/pm-powersave.log`. You should be able to read the log file, and see that `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/powersave-policy-hda-powerdown false:success.` means that it ran the program/script "`powersave-policy-hda-powerdown false`" and that the result was "`success`", for each line in the log file, especially the ones that don't have "success". Then read the failing script and decide if it is reasonable for your system. Read `man pm-powersave`.